# Can I use web deploy to install an web api and self-host it?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

I want to deploy a web api package I created in a server using web-deploy and self host it with OWIN. It's the first time I use web deploy and the issue is, all the examples I have found on web-deploy are for IIS hosting so my question is can I use web deploy to install an api and self host it?

Comment: *all the examples I have found on web-deploy are for IIS hosting* No surprises there ... https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy *Web Deploy (msdeploy) simplifies deployment of Web applications and Web sites to IIS servers.*

Comment: Is there a similar method for self-hosted web applications?

Comment: how are you self hosting? Windows Service or WAS?

Comment: You can manually install it as a service using the `ServiceBase` class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase(v=vs.110).aspx Or you can use TopShelf which abstracts the service installation away and provide a simple-to-use library http://topshelf-project.com/ If you're using ASP.NET Core then you can use the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/windows-service

Comment: TopShelf works great, it also makes debugging a lot easier. thanks.